# Who can give the sacrament of confirmation in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments, confirmation

Out of curiosity, when someone plans to recieve the Sacrament of Confirmation, do they have to recieve this Sacrament from a bishop or cardinal, or can any ordained minister give this Sacrament?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bishop has the power to confirm, but this power can be delegated to a priest.

See the [*Catechism of the Council of Trent*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5864)'s [section on Confirmation](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Confirmation.shtml):

> **Minister of Confirmation**
>
> Pastors should also teach to whom especially has been committed the
>   administration of this Sacrament; for as, according to the Prophet,
>   there are many who run without being sent, it is necessary to teach
>   who are its true and legitimate ministers, in order that the faithful
>   may be enabled to receive the Sacrament and grace of Confirmation.
>
> Now the Holy Scriptures show that **the Bishop alone is the ordinary
>   minister of this Sacrament**, because we read in the Acts of the
>   Apostles that when Samaria had received the Word of God, Peter and
>   John were sent to them, who prayed for them that they might receive
>   the Holy Ghost: for he was not as yet come upon any of them, but they
>   were only baptised. Here we may see that he who had baptised, having
>   been only a deacon, had no power to confirm; but that its
>   administration was reserved to a more perfect order of ministers, that
>   is, to the Apostles. The same may be observed whenever the Sacred
>   Scriptures make mention of this Sacrament.
>
> Nor are there wanting in proof of this matter the clearest testimonies
>   of the holy Fathers and of Popes Urban, Eusebius, Damasus, Innocent
>   and Leo, as is evident from their decrees. St. Augustine, also,
>   seriously complains of the corrupt practice of the Egyptians and
>   Alexandrians, whose priests dared to administer the Sacrament of
>   Confirmation.
>
> The thorough propriety of reserving this function to Bishops the
>   pastor may illustrate by the following comparison. As in the
>   construction of buildings the artisans, who are inferior agents,
>   prepare and dispose cement, lime, timbers and the other material,
>   while to the architect belongs the completion of the work; so in like
>   manner this Sacrament, which is, at it were, the completion of the
>   spiritual edifice, should be performed by no other than the chief
>   priest.

Comment: The only thing I could see adding to the answer is maybe a brief description of typical circumstances when confirmation might be delegated to the priest.

Comment: @MattGutting Such as if the bishop doesn't have time to do the confirmation himself

Comment: Exactly. That's the kind of thing that should be added to the answer.